# Session-Id creation in JSP?

Tags: jsp, session, session-cookies

Session Id is created for a particular user or particular web-app ?
say there are two apps running on server, the user 1st makes request to 1st app, needing a session, so a session ID is created!
now he makes request to another, so will another session id be created or the same id will be used there as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Session is created per app and multiple apps cannot share a session.

I would relate this to as two different application. Sharing session with two different apps will lead to security risk.

Hope that helps.